# Resource Style is not working in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, textbox, styles, datatemplate

I have the following resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFBF" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=EntryEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CommodityTemplate">
        <Grid Width="218" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,.5" Background="LightCyan" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Item_Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2,0" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Size}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="8" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Unit}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="8" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Qty_Order, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12" Margin="2,1"  />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=Qty_Filled, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12" Margin="2,1" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EntryEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryTemplate">
        <Grid Width="225">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5" Background="AliceBlue"/>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,.5" />
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5,0" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Category.Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Quantity Ordered" FontSize="7" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Quantity filled" FontSize="7" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CommodityTemplate}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

In my control, I have numerous TextBox controls.

I then have the following LiewView control which utilizes the CategoryTemplate. This template contains another ListView control which utilizes the CommodityTemplate.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Category_List}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryTemplate}" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="LightGray" >
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

I also have a CheckBox control which if checked, I want all the TextBox controls to be disabled.

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="Has Been Picked-Up" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Received, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0" Padding="5,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CBrec_Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The Received and EntryEnabled properties are found in my ViewModel.

```
    #region Received

    /// <summary>ViewModel property: Received of type: Boolean points to OrderForm.Received</summary>
    public Boolean Received
    {
        get
        {
            if (OrderForm == null) return false;
            return OrderForm.Received;
        }
        set
        {
            if (OrderForm == null) return;
            OrderForm.Received = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Received");
            OnPropertyChanged("EntryEnabled");
        }
    }

    #endregion

   #region EntryEnabled

    /// <summary>Property EntryEnabled of type Boolean</summary>
    public Boolean EntryEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            if (OrderForm == null) return false;
            return OrderForm.Received == false;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("EntryEnabled");
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

When I check the CheckBox, all of the TextBox controls disable as expected, except for the Textbox controls found in the CommodityTemplate.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.  I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It's going to bind to `EntryEnabled` on the TextBox's `DataContext`, which will be the `DataTemplate`'s `DataContext` -- the class instance that's being shown by the `DataTemplate`. What class is displayed by `CommodityTemplate`? Does it have an `EntryEnabled` property? I don't seen any TextBox controls in any other *template* here. My guess is that `EntryEnabled` is a property of the `UserControl`'s viewmodel, not of the commodity class. The solution is probably `Value="{Binding DataContext.EntryEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`.

Comment: Bonus: Quick and easy way to find out were a Binding is going wrong: `"{Binding EntryEnabled, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"`, then watch the output pane in VS at runtime. It'll tell you everything it's doing to resolve the thing, and where it fails. Since Bindings have such minimal design-time support or compile-time checking, this is extremely useful.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `EntryEnabled` is a property of the viewmodel of the `UserControl`, not of the `Commodity` class (I'm guessing at the name). But in that `DataTemplate`, `Commodity` is the `DataContext`. This matters because that binding will look for the property on the `DataContext` of the `TextBox`. It sounds like all your other TextBoxes are running around loose in the `UserControl`, so their `DataContext` is the `UserControl`'s viewmodel.

From inside the template, you can bind to the same viewmodel, with a little extra work:

```
Value="{Binding DataContext.EntryEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```